# Display variuos size of ListElements with GridView

Tags: qt, gridview, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

Iam relatively new to qml and maybe my attempt is wrong, so please, if you have another idea for solving the issue, please do not hesitate to write it down.

**Problem:**

I need to Display varoius sizes of ListElemts (which can be dragged and dropped). The main Container is 200px x 180px. The smalles List element is 100px x 60px, the secound size should be 200px x 60px and the biggest should be 200px x 120 px. So I found an Qt example and modified it to my needs, but I have problems regarding the automatic placement of the ListElements.

It works perfect for only small ListElements like here:

[image: only small Elements]

Now, if I need a big one, GridView is placing them for Expample like this one:

[image: CellWith and CellHeight set]

In this Example, the View is much larger in width like 200px. (gragging the ListElements around may sort them other way, but not proper.)

In the last test, I removed CellWidth and Cell height:

[image]

The traget is to display all cells in a 200px x 180px Grid. 
As said, maybe my attempt is wrong. Do anyone of you guys have a solution for me?
Here is the modified code. For testing, I commented out things and altered the size property:

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 480
height: 272
title: qsTr("Hello World")


GridView {
    id: root
    width: 200; height: 180
    cellWidth: 100; cellHeight: 60

    displaced: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }
    }

//! [0]
    model: DelegateModel {
//! [0]
        id: visualModel
        model: ListModel {
            id: colorModel
            ListElement { color: "blue"; size:1}
            ListElement { color: "green"; size:1 }
            ListElement { color: "red"; size: 1 }
           ListElement { color: "yellow"; size: 1 }
           ListElement { color: "orange"; size: 1 }
           ListElement { color: "purple"; size: 1 }
        }
//! [1]
        delegate: MouseArea {
            id: delegateRoot

            property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

            width:{
               switch (model.size) {
               case 1:
                   return 100;
               case 2:
                   return 200;
               case 3:
                   return 200;
               }

            }
            height: {
                switch (model.size) {
                case 1:
                    return 60;
                case 2:
                    return 60;
                case 3:
                    return 120;
                }
            }

            drag.target: icon

            Rectangle {
                id: icon
                width:{
                   switch (model.size) {
                   case 1:
                       return 100;
                   case 2:
                       return 200;
                   case 3:
                       return 200;
                   }

                }
                height: {
                    switch (model.size) {
                    case 1:
                        return 60;
                    case 2:
                        return 60;
                    case 3:
                        return 120;
                    }
                }
                anchors {
                    horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                color: model.color
                radius: 3

                Drag.active: delegateRoot.drag.active
                Drag.source: delegateRoot
                Drag.hotSpot.x: icon.width/2
                Drag.hotSpot.y: icon.height/2

                states: [
                    State {
                        when: icon.Drag.active
                        ParentChange {
                            target: icon
                            parent: root
                        }

                        AnchorChanges {
                            target: icon;
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined;
                            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

            DropArea {
                anchors { fill: parent; margins: 0 }

                onEntered: visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex)
            }
        }
//! [1]
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for all your thoughts/suggestions!

Edit:

To clear up the questions, here a gif with showd correct rearrangement when drag and drop items:
[image]

This Picture shows the the problems I decribed. Some items are overlapping:

[image]

This picture is showing the problem with not setted cellWidth and cellHeight of GridView.

[image]

As far as I understand, GridView don´t care about the size of its elements. Positioning Elements depends on the cellWith and cellHeight Values. But is it possible to configure GridView the way I need (do not overlap, let items not come outside bonds)?
Or is GradView maybe the wrong attempt to realize this?
If anyone need more information, I will be happy to provide!

Comment: It is not clear to me which configuration you want to obtain. Can you generate an image of the layout you want? Is your problem related to drag and drop or (static) layout ordering?

Comment: My problem is related to drag&drop. When using drag and drop in the first example, all items are rearranged correctly. If the items are mixed (small and big items), the rearrangement of the items don't work properly, like you can see on the 2nd picture. In general, I can drag and drop every items, but I need the other Items to be rearranged in the borders of 200px x 180px. I will try to add pictures asap.

Comment: A `Grid/GridView` is as the name suggests a grid. If you want to have one element span over multiple cells, you would need some *dummy elements* accordingly placed in the model, so those cells are kept free. Maybe a `Flow` would help you, but I think it is also rows/columns-based.

Comment: Possibly related to: [How does one create a staggered grid view in QML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152097/how-does-one-create-a-staggered-grid-view-in-qml)

Comment: Maybe interesting: https://github.com/ruedigergad/FlowListView (Not tried!) -> https://ruedigergad.com/2012/11/24/qml-flowlistview/

Comment: @derM thank your for the hint with dummy elements. The problem to solve is, that dummy elements are moving, too. So the layout will be inconsistent. I played around with this approach some hours and will check what I can reach. The link with FlowListView view i found already, maybe I have to check if this could be a solution for me, too. It seems it will be a very hard time for me. Thanks again!