# QML Staggered (Masonry) GridView or Flow

Tags: javascript, gridview, qml, grid-layout, masonry

I've come across the same issue raised in the following question:

[How does one create a staggered grid view in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152097/how-does-one-create-a-staggered-grid-view-in-qml)

I am looking to implement either a `Flow` `GridLayout` or `GridView` in a Masonry style, see attached pictures of current output and desired.

CURRENT:

[image: Current output]

DESIRED:

[image: Desired output]

I am not looking to use an external library for this; instead work purely with QML and JavaScript.

I have tried things such as a Flow within a Flickable:

```
Flickable
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 5
    contentHeight: flow.height

    Flow {
        id: flow
        width: parent.width
        height: 800
        spacing: 10
        flow: Flow.TopToBottom
        Repeater{
            model: [80,60,120,75,90,55,140,50,70,90,80,60,120,75,90]
            Rectangle {
                height: modelData
                width: 100
                border.color: "black"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also with my GridLayout working with the `preferredHeight` and `fillHeight`:

```
Layout.fillWidth: true
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.preferredWidth: Layout.columnSpan
Layout.preferredHeight: Layout.rowSpan
```

However both present the problem of the rowHeight being set to the tallest object per row.

**MY QUESTION IS**

How can I create unequal cell size in a grid where the rows are not locked to the tallest object for a masonry view?

The only 'hacky' solution that's come to mind is now have two lists, one whose model is every odd index, the other every even index attached to the same flickable so they scroll as one object, but surely there must be a better way to achieve a masonry view with no whitespace? I have tested this and it does work; (see below) but again, is there a better way to implement?

```
    function isEven(n) {
        return n % 2 == 0;
    }

    function isOdd(n) {
        return Math.abs(n % 2) == 1;
    }

    JsonListModel {
        id: jsonModel; source: userFeed; keyField: "id"
        fields: ["id", "owner", "downloadUrl","profile_Pic_URL", "tag", "timestamp","post_description", "team", "liked_by", "location"]
    }
    SortFilterProxyModel {
        id: sortedModelOdd;
        Component.onCompleted: {app.userFeedChanged();sourceModel = jsonModel}
        filters: [
            ExpressionFilter {expression: model.tag === exploreFilter},
            ExpressionFilter {expression: isOdd(index)}
        ]
        sorters: RoleSorter {roleName: "timestamp"; ascendingOrder: false}
    }
    SortFilterProxyModel {
        id: sortedModelEven;
        Component.onCompleted: {app.userFeedChanged();sourceModel = jsonModel}
        filters: [
            ExpressionFilter {expression: model.tag === exploreFilter},
            ExpressionFilter {expression: isEven(index)}
        ]
        sorters: RoleSorter {roleName: "timestamp"; ascendingOrder: false}
    }

// i create 2 versions of the same model by using my expressionFilter for odds/evens

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Row {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: dp(5)
            anchors.margins: dp(5)
            AppListView {
                id: evenModelView
                model: sortedModelEven; emptyText.text: qsTr("No posts yet!"); scale: 0.96
                width: parent.width/2; spacing: dp(5); scrollIndicatorVisible: false;
                delegate: AppImage {width: parent.width; fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit; source: model.downloadUrl}
            }
            AppListView {
                id: oddModelView
                model: sortedModelOdd; emptyText.text: qsTr("No posts yet!"); scale: 0.96
                width: parent.width/2; spacing: dp(5);scrollIndicatorVisible: false;
                delegate: AppImage {width: parent.width; fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit; source: model.downloadUrl}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Slight update to my 'hacky' solution - Using a scrollview caused my app to no longer load in testing (which I think is due to too much being loaded at once); Placing my Row{AppListView{} AppListView{}} into a loader when the page was loaded (Component.onCompleted{}) did the trick however also simply changing the ScrollView to a Flickable works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution (which I touched on in my question - and refined it) so will post as answer but still happy to hear if anyone achieves this result using actual Layouts ect.

```
    JsonListModel {
        id: jsonModel; source: jsonArray; keyField: "id"
        fields: ["id", "owner", "downloadUrl","profile_Pic_URL", "tag", "timestamp","post_description", "team", "liked_by", "location"]
    }
    SortFilterProxyModel {
        id: sortedModelOdd; Component.onCompleted: {sourceModel = jsonModel}
        filters: [ExpressionFilter {expression: model.tag === exploreFilter; enabled: exploreFilter !== "Everything"}, ExpressionFilter {expression: isOdd(index)}]
        sorters: RoleSorter {roleName: "timestamp"; ascendingOrder: false}
    }
    SortFilterProxyModel {
        id: sortedModelEven; Component.onCompleted: {sourceModel = jsonModel}
        filters: [ExpressionFilter {expression: model.tag === exploreFilter; enabled: exploreFilter !== "Everything"}, ExpressionFilter {expression: isEven(index)}]
        sorters: RoleSorter {roleName: "timestamp"; ascendingOrder: false}
    }


    AppFlickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent; contentHeight: scrollRow.height + dp(Theme.navigationBar.height)*2; anchors.topMargin: scrollModel.height
        Row {
            id: scrollRow; width: parent.width
            Column {
                id: col; spacing: dp(5); width: parent.width/2
                Behavior on y {
                    NumberAnimation {properties: "y"; duration: 1000 }
                }
                Repeater {

                    id: evenModelView; model: sortedModelEven;
                    delegate: AppCard {
                        id: evenImage; width: (parent.width)-dp(2); margin: dp(5); paper.radius: dp(5); scale: 0.96;
                        media: AppImage {
                            width: parent.width; fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit; source: model.downloadUrl; autoTransform: true
                            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onPressAndHold: PictureViewer.show(homePage, model.downloadUrl); onReleased: PictureViewer.close(); onClicked: {exploreStack.push(viewPostComp, {postID: model.id})}}
                        }
                        content: AppText {
                            width: parent.width; padding: dp(15); maximumLineCount: 2; elide: Text.ElideRight; wrapMode: Text.Wrap; text: model.owner.username
                            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: exploreStack.push(otherUserComp, {userID: model.owner.id})}
                        }
                        actions: Row {
                            IconButton {
                                icon: {
                                    var likedList = Object.keys(model.liked_by.list)
                                    likedList.indexOf(userData.id) ? IconType.heart : IconType.hearto}
                                onClicked: {likedList.indexOf(userData.id) ? dataModel.likePost(model.id, false, model.liked_by.count, model.owner.id) : dataModel.likePost(model.id, true, model.liked_by.count, model.owner.id)}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Column {
                id: oddCol; spacing: dp(5); width: parent.width/2
                Repeater {
                    id: oddModelView; model: sortedModelOdd;
                    delegate: AppCard {
                        id: oddImage; width: (parent.width)-dp(2); margin: dp(5); paper.radius: dp(5); scale: 0.96;
                        media: AppImage {
                            width: parent.width; fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit; source: model.downloadUrl; autoTransform: true
                            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onPressAndHold:  PictureViewer.show(homePage, model.downloadUrl); onReleased: PictureViewer.close(); onClicked: {exploreStack.push(viewPostComp, {postID: model.id})}}
                        }
                        content: AppText{
                            width: parent.width; padding: dp(15); maximumLineCount: 2; elide: Text.ElideRight; wrapMode: Text.Wrap; text: model.owner.username;
                            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: exploreStack.push(otherUserComp, {userID: model.owner.id})}
                        }
                        actions: Row {
                            IconButton {
                                icon: {
                                    var likedList = Object.keys(model.liked_by.list)
                                    likedList.indexOf(userData.id) ? IconType.heart : IconType.hearto}
                                onClicked: {likedList.indexOf(userData.id) ? dataModel.likePost(model.id, false, model.liked_by.count, model.owner.id) : dataModel.likePost(model.id, true, model.liked_by.count, model.owner.id)}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Notes:**

I used a `ScrollView` initially instead of a `Flickable`, however this caused serious performance issues.

I placed this inside of a `Loader` which did resolve the issue somewhat as it wasn't tearing into performance at runtime, I then changed to a `Flickable`, which has caused 0 issues thus far (yet to test with a large model).

Each `AppListView` needs it's interactive disabled otherwise sometimes scrolling can catch onto only one of the columns and put them out of sync.

(See picture of implemented result) [image: Dev_Screenshot of style achieved]

Comment: Could you post the whole solution? seems interesting

Comment: Hey @Moia absolutely, give me a few hours and I'll edit and let you know!

Comment: are few hours passed? :D

Comment: My word @Moia I am so sorry!!! I'll say that was 'a few hours' in my wife's time! I've updated my "answer" with the full segment, normally I try to trim off any excess for stack :) if you have any questions on any part of it absolutely let me know :) (note. this isn't the entire page; simple what applies to the model, I can also upload a screenshot if you'd like to see it in action)